# What is benefit of diode in the RC circuit

Tags: resistors, diodes

[image]

This picture for reset circuit of the [8284A clock generator](http://manualzz.com/doc/23777779/clock-generator-8284a) can you tell me what is the benefit of diode in the circuit?

Second question why has the resistor been added between crystal an ground?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It's difficult to read your schematic with the grid on. Please also capitalise and punctuate the title and post properly for legibility and credibility.

Comment: http://manualzz.com/doc/23777779/clock-generator-8284a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks non-functional doesn't it!

However, the designer has cleverly anticipated what happens when you cycle the power on this circuit. When the 5V goes away, without that diode the capacitor would remain charged for some time. Reapplying power too soon might prevent the reset signal being generated.

The diode provides a short path to discharge the capacitor when the rail goes to ground.

It may however be superfluous if the input of the device has internal diodes to protect it from over-voltages on the pins. But even then, those diodes might not like 10uF charged to Vcc over Vcc hung on them.

BTW it is a common mistake to forget to think about, and designing for, what happens when the power is removed.

Your second question... See Transistors answer. Generally devices like this indicate how the crystal should be wired in their data sheet. It is important to accurately follow their recommendations. Even then, once the PCB stage is reached, some tweaking can be required.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you tell me what is the benefit of diode in the circuit?

- C1 is the reset time delay capacitor. On power up it should be 0 V and after \$ \tau = RC = 10k \cdot 10 \mu = 0.1 \ \mathrm s \$ it will release the reset.
- D1 ensures that when power is switched off that the capacitor will rapidly discharge into the positive rail. This ensures that the proper reset will take place on power-up.

> Second question why he adding the resistor between crystal an ground?

It looks like its part of a common base crystal oscillator.

[image]

*Figure 1. A common base crystal oscillator. Source: [Bipolar Transistor Cookbook](http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/bipolar_transistor_cookbook_part_5).*

> Finally, Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMctj.jpg) shows an exceptionally useful two-transistor oscillator that can be used with any 50 kHz to 10 MHz series-resonant crystal. Q1 is wired as a common-base amplifier and Q2 as an emitter follower, and the output signal (from Q2 emitter) is fed back to the input (Q1 emitter) via C2 and the series-resonant crystal. This excellent circuit will oscillate with any crystal that shows the slightest sign of life.

R4 and R5 are R1 and R2 of your schematic. C2 may not be critical.

Answer (score 0):

> Second question why has the resistor been added between crystal an
>   ground?

Data sheet suggests that another crystal arrangement is possible, provided that stray capacitance from pins X1 and X2 to ground is small. A small-value variable capacitor in series with the crystal provides a method to adjust oscillator frequency:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWDVlF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Where a "series-resonant" crystal is specified, the oscillator pins (X1 and X2) likely work best at low-impedance. The extra 510 ohm resistors may ensure that this is the case, and they would tend to swamp out the effect of stray capacitance to ground. This is a guess, since no internal circuit description (of any data sheet that I could find) shows internal amplifier configuration.